# sql server return long.parse show error

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

My current problem is with SQL server. I'm writing my own queries and one query is for `INSERT` data inside table. That's easy to do. What isn't easy is error i received during testing. I just breakpointed every steps and all works fine, except final result.

Is the problem with long? Because when I use `bool`, it works perfectly, but I need to use long.

Now let's see what I have inside code:

```
public long Create(TPerson person)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var insert = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO CisOsoba(Jmeno, Prijmeni, Email, TelKlapka, TelKlapka2, TelMob)
                                         VALUES(@jmeno, @prijmeni, @email, @telKlapka, @telKlapka2, @telMob)");

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jmeno", person.FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prijmeni", person.LastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", person.Email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telKlapka", person.Phone1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telKlapka2", person.Phone2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telMob", person.PhoneMob);

        return long.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }
}
```

When I have breakpoint at line: `return long.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());` and I jump inside, there is a error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Business.WeighingSystem.dll
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."

I have really no idea, what object I don't have to set instance.

Thanks for every tip! :)

Comment: The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What value do you want to return? Based on the signature, I would expect the ID of the person just created to be returned, but the answer you've got so far will give you a different number.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to add `;SELECT IDENT_CURRENT()` in the insert query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are trying to return the number of rows affected by the command. In this case you need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead:

```
return long.Parse(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

Based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Comment: Thanks mate. It working like a charm! You are genius :)